# Postgrsql - result as false for translate and any json comparision

Tags: sql, postgresql

in postgres trying to execute below SQL giving me false result.

```
SELECT translate('owner=\"ganga','"', '')=any('{owner=\"ganga}');
```

if I remove double quotes it works perfectly.

Comment: This doubleqote is prceded by \ so please include that and execute whoever is executing.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you prefix your single-quoted constant with an [`E` to enable C-style escaping](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS-UESCAPE), or with [`U&` to enable Unicode escaping](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS-UESCAPE), backslash `\` doesn't have any special meaning in there in terms of stored value; it is *not* discarded after being interpreted, the value retains it. If you want to see the "raw" value, you can use [`quote_literal()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#id-1.5.8.10.7.2.2.14.1.1.1): [demo at db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/eoPeZfHd)

```
create table test (column1 text);
insert into test values ('a\"b\"c'),('a"b"c')
returning column1, length(column1), quote_literal(column1);
```

| column1 | length | quote_literal |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a"b"c | 7 | E'a\"b\"c' |
| a"b"c | 5 | 'a"b"c' |

They do affect how the value is parsed and presented later, hiding it, but the backslash is in there the whole time.

Your `translate()` call treats the `\"` as two separate characters and you asked it to wipe only the `"`, so it did. The string on the right still has both the double-quote and that backslash in it, so you obviously won't get a match. My guess is you read them both out and they *looked* equal, which caused the confusion.

One thing you might do is reconsider if escaping double quotes in either case is really necessary. You might also want to construct the array on the right using an [`array[]` constructor](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html#ARRAYS-INPUT) `=any(array['owner="ganga'])` to save yourself keeping track of what the array literal `'{a,b,c\,d}'` form will end up as. [See this](https://dbfiddle.uk/IeeWTMb-):

```
select e, quote_literal(e) 
from unnest('{"a",b  ,c\,d}'::text[])_(e);
```

| e | quote_literal |
| --- | --- |
| a | 'a' |
| b | 'b' |
| c,d | 'c,d' |

The backslash `\` is in the text constant, which gets parsed to become an array. The resulting array element *does not* retain it: it prevented the comma between `c` and `d` from being treated as a delimiter, but it doesn't get a second shot as a part of the resulting value. To achieve both, you'd need to triple it: `'{a,b,c\\\,d}'`. One escapes the comma `,`, second one escapes the third one, the third one gets through to become a part of the element. It's a bit easier to understand that from `array['a', 'b', 'c\,d']`.